# Can't find the textbox with FindControl C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, findcontrol

I ran into an issue trying to find a textbox control on the same page. It keeps giving me a null when I debug it.

**Here is my code:**

```html
public void UpdateTimeLog(string input)
    {
        string timeNumber = "txtTime" + input;
        TextBox myTextbox = (TextBox)FindControl(timeNumber);

        sqlConnection.Open();
        using (var command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [JobSheet] SET [Time" + input + "]=@Time" + input + " WHERE [JobShtId]=@JobShtId", sqlConnection))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobShtId", jobSheetId);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time" + input + "", myTextbox.Text);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        sqlConnection.Close();
    }
```

**Problem Solved:** I didn't specify that the textbox control was in a container(e.g. ContentPlaceHolder1).

Here is the corrected code:

```html
public void UpdateTimeLog(string input)
    {
        var container = Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
        string timeNumber = "txtTime" + input;
        TextBox myTextbox = (TextBox)container.FindControl(timeNumber);

        sqlConnection.Open();
        using (var command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [JobSheet] SET [Time" + input + "]=@Time" + input + " WHERE [JobShtId]=@JobShtId", sqlConnection))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobShtId", jobSheetId);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time" + input + "", myTextbox.Text);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        sqlConnection.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Instead of find control.. Please try Page.FindControl & this.Page.FindControl and let me know if it helps you

Comment: Where is the textbox defined? is it in some other container control like gridview?

Comment: I did that but it didn't work. I found out why it kept returning null, and the reason was because I didn't specify that the control was in a container. For example, the ContentPlaceHolder1

Comment: Please try it should work....
var container = Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
var control = container.FindControl("txtNaam1");

Comment: Thank you @maulik sakhare, I just realized that a few minutes ago!

Answer (score 1):

you should just send your textbox as the sender object like this:

```
UpdateTimeLog("2",(TextBox)sender);
```

of course you'll need to modify your method too to accept the TextBox object.

and this only makes sense when you're using the same event handler for more than one text box.

Answer (score 1):

it should be Work try it,

```
 TextBox myTextBox = (TextBox)(this.Controls[("txtTime" + input)]).Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to find control by ID.so try this code

```
public static Control[] FlattenHierachy(Control root)
        {
            List<Control> list = new List<Control>();
            list.Add(root);
            if (root.HasControls())
            {
                foreach (Control control in root.Controls)
                {
                    list.AddRange(FlattenHierachy(control));
                }
            }
            return list.ToArray();
        }
```

and

```
  public void UpdateTimeLog(string input)
        {
            string timeNumber = "txtTime" + input;
           // TextBox myTextbox = (TextBox)FindControl(timeNumber);
            Control[] allControls = FlattenHierachy(Page);
            foreach (Control control in allControls)
            {
                TextBox textBox = control as TextBox;
                if (textBox != null && textBox.ID == timeNumber)
                {
                    textBox.Text = "Hello";//Do your other stuff
                }
            }

          //Rest is ommited
        }
```

Comment: Awesome! I like this way better. Thank you for sharing this with me